# Why is my process always showing in the DDMS processes list?

Tags: android, process, ddms

Using DDMS, I see 3 processes active in my Android: Viber, logitech harmony and a process with my package name.
The thing is that I never created any process.

**Why have Android opened a process on my behalf?** For what purpose?

Also, why can't I see all the other apps' processes, like gmail, maps, etc. even when they are found in the foreground?

Some thoughts: I do listen to folder changes using a [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html). Perhaps that's the thing? Perhaps it's something related to running the app in a development environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why have Android opened a process on my behalf? For what purpose?

Because you ran your application.

> Also, why can't I see all the other apps' processes, like gmail, maps, etc. even when they are found in the foreground?

Because they are not compiled in debug mode. On a production device, only debug builds (or apps with `android:debuggable` set to `true` in the manifest) will appear in DDMS.

Comment: Indeed, When running an apk built as a production product, the process is not visible in the DDMS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each app is launched in a separate process. Hence your app is being shown as a process. Perhaps other apps are not active on your phone hence they are not being shown.

Comment: They are active. As I said, I even put run them in the foreground.

Comment: Have you seen your app in DDMS, even though you don't manually create a process?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the phone is starved for memory, Android keeps processes alive just in case. When you close an activity, the process stays.

That, or you might have a service running. When a service is running in your app, Android treats the process with even more respect, meaning it gets shut down only after all the do-nothing processes are shut down.

Comment: I do have a service, but I think lots of app have services running in the background but I don't see them.

Comment: For instance, I play some music using the built-in music player but I don't see its process in the list of processes.